# Unable to display a background image

Tags: html, image, css

I am trying to set multiple background images for my page but I am unable to do so using an external CSS file and I don't know if I am doing something wrong or there is something wrong with Notepad++ or XAMPP because my code seems to be functional.

NOTE:

- The images I am using has all the permissions turned on.
- I am able to see the image if I use in-line CSS but not when I use an
  external CSS file.
- I am also able to see the image when i use the image tag.

Image Tag (this Works)

```
<img src="img/bg1.png" alt="">
```

Test HTML Document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test</title>

            <!-- Custom Cascading Styling Sheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-styles.css">

        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

External CSS Code: custom-styles.css

Example 1 (this doesn't work):

```
    body {
        background-image: url('img/bg1.png'), url('img/bg2.png'), url('img/bg3.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
    }
```

Example 2 (this doesn't work):

```
    body {
        background-image: url('img/bg1.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
    }
```

Example 3 (this doesn't work):

```
body {
    background-image: url('img/bg1.png');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images in external css files are relative to that css file. Images inside your html (be it an img tag or (inline) css) are relative to that html document.

Supposing you have a structure like this:

```
/
/css
  style.css
/img
  image.jpeg
index.html
```

Inside `index.html` you would reference that image as `img/image.jpeg`. Inside `style.css` however, you would have to go up one directory first, so the url would become `../img/image.jpeg`.

You could also use absolute urls, or url relative to the root. Those would work in any file they are referenced from. So if you would use `http://example.com/img/image.jpeg` or `/img/image.jpeg` those should work anywhere. Do note that full urls are a pain when developing on localhost, as your hostname will probably be different then online.

To debug these kind of issues (in chrome), you should open your developer console, go to the "network" tab, filter by "img" and look for any lines in the list that are red. They will most likely say that a 404 response was returned from the server (the image was not found). Check the urls the browser is trying to fetch. It should be easy to spot what went wrong if you know the directory structure of your site. Also note that you can see who initiated the request in the initiator column. Clicking on the link brings you straight to the line of code that requested the image.

[image]

Comment: I saw where I went wrong. I needed to go one directory up in order to gain access to the image directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the relative path, so I'm guessing all you need is:

```
body {
    background-image: url('/img/bg1.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`background: url('../../../static/images/index_hero.jpg');`

```css
.nameofclass {
    background: url('../../../static/images/index_hero.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

But the following code itself worked for me

```
body {
background-image: url('img/a.png');
}
```

You just follow trail and error method from html template from simple code..

Caution : check whether you have turned off image viewing in your bowser.
:-))))

Comment: Image viewing is not turned off. I have resorted to doing it in a simple HTML document and all I get is a blank page when I run it. I checked the css reference link which seem not be the problem either.